On the below Tradingview pinescript RSI crossover, I need an alert on plotchar only when crossover occurs "every third time"
On the below RSI crossover, I need an alert on plotchar only when crossover occurs "every third time"
//@version=5
indicator(title="Stochastic RSI", shorttitle="Stoch RSI", format=format.price, precision=2, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)
smoothK = input.int(3, "K", minval=1)
smoothD = input.int(3, "D", minval=1)
lengthRSI = input.int(14, "RSI Length", minval=1)
lengthStoch = input.int(14, "Stochastic Length", minval=1)
src = input(close, title="RSI Source")
rsi1 = ta.rsi(src, lengthRSI)
k = ta.sma(ta.stoch(rsi1, rsi1, rsi1, lengthStoch), smoothK)
d = ta.sma(k, smoothD)
//plot(k, "K", color=#2962FF)
plot(d, "D", color=#FF6D00)
h0 = hline(80, "Upper Band", color=#787B86)
hline(50, "Middle Band", color=color.new(#787B86, 50))
h1 = hline(20, "Lower Band", color=#787B86)
fill(h0, h1, color=color.rgb(33, 150, 243, 90), title="Background")

// declaration
var int counter = 0
var bool alertTriggered = false

//crossovers up and dows
srsi_down = ta.crossunder(d,80)
srsi_up = ta.crossover(d,20)

// Increment the counter when srsi_down occurs
if srsi_down
    counter := counter + 1

// Check if the counter is divisible by 3 and srsi_downis true
if counter % 3 == 0 and srsi_down
    srsi_down
    alertTriggered := true

// Plotting the counter value on the chart for visualization

plotchar(srsi_down, "Enter Down","*",location = location.bottom, size = size.normal,color = color.white)

Signal on Plotchar occurs on every crossover but am looking signal to occur on every third occurance
